# vb.net stuck on AWS Redshift Copy command

Tags: .net, vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to fill a Redshift table with data from CUR files that are in S3, by using the Copy Command on the RedshiftManifest.json file that is in the folder with the CUR files.

The data has about 15 million lines and everything works fine with about half as much data and it also works fine with all the data if I just execute the copy command in SQL Workbench, but if I execute it for the whole dataset in my code in vb.net, it's forever stuck on the execution of the command even when the data is already available in Redshift after about 15 minutes.

```
Dim conn As New OdbcConnection(connString)
conn.Open()
Dim command As New OdbcCommand()
Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter()

command.Connection = conn
command.CommandText = commandText
da.UpdateCommand = command
da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It's stuck on the last line here.

Comment: Ever heard of stored procedure ? Try to implement that and it might actually help :)

Comment: what is the text of the copy command? does it just hang there? have you tried executing the command manually outside of vb?